# Dedicated hosting provider in Ireland

Tags: windows, hosting

I am looking for a decent dedicated (or cloud) host in  Ireland. Can you recommend someone or share your experience?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen these guys advertised a lot, but, not tried them: http://www.blacknight.com/

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's European data centre for its cloud services is in Ireland: http://aws.amazon.com